# F# List functions and let bindings: Changing a variable name appears to cause an error (unexpected infix in operator binding)

Tags: f#, f#-3.0

So I have these 2 files on Try F#. The only difference (that I can see) is the variable name. They are both 3 lines of code. They are hosted right now on Try F#

http://www.tryfsharp.org/create/zadkielmodeler/file1.fsx

[http://www.tryfsharp.org/create/zadkielmodeler/file2.fsx](http://www.tryfsharp.org/create/zadkielmodeler/file1.fsx)

File 1 works , File 2 does not.

I am struggling to wrap my brain around why.
I was trying a similar situation in my own code for a personal project.

```
let x1Points = [0..2..100]
  |> List.map (fun x-> x * x)
```

This yields the same error in my test file online (file2)
On the first line

```
"Incomplete Value or function definition."
```

On the second line of code it says this:

```
Unexpected infix operator in binding
```

Honestly, I don't know what that means.
In any event, If I can understand why it gives me this error in the test files,
I can understand it better for my real project. So please help me understand why I am getting this error in file2, but not file1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the example you have given is because you need more indentation

this works:

```
 let x1Points = [0..2..100]
                |> List.map (fun x-> x * x);;
```

You have the same issue in your second example, changing it to

```
let xpoints =[0..100]
          |> List.filter (fun xpoints -> xpoints % 2 = 0)
          |> List.map (fun xpoints -> xpoints * 2)
```

works

Comment: So does the  |> operator have to be doubly indented? Or does it have to be indented to be inline with the initial list?

Comment: It looks like the rule is that it has to be indented to the end of the previous declaration

Answer (score 8):

Simple indentation issue.  Using the name `x` aligns the lower pipeline code with the end of the identifier name.  Using `xpoints` causes the lower pipeline code to be "offsides."  Just adjust to

```
let xpoints =[0..100]
             |> List.filter (fun xpoints -> xpoints % 2 = 0)
             |> List.map (fun xpoints -> xpoints * 2)
```

or better yet (this is "standard" style I'd say)

```
let xpoints =
    [0..100]
    |> List.filter (fun xpoints -> xpoints % 2 = 0)
    |> List.map (fun xpoints -> xpoints * 2)
```